Where does Chrome store these data types?
So I was checking out the types of data that Chrome stores and I came across this on Google's support page: 
Cookies 
Site data 
Handlers 
Media licenses 
Where exactly does Chrome store them?

I see that the support page already has explanations. Which in particular do you want more detail on?

I want to know where does chrome store the data (well i know where cookies are stored but not the others)

It the same location, within the users Chrome profile, editing your question to clarify what your actual question is will lead to an actual answer
